# Incoming Spam Mail to my mail id's in my website

Tags: exim, cpanel

I am getting lot's of incoming spam mail's to mail id's in my websites such as (info@domain.com, infouk@domain.com) mostly to info pages not to user's mail account. How to stop mail from such mail id's. I have exim mail server with `cpanel` and `whm` account.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have root or whm access?
Check exim report and that will show how spam coming, but if you don't have access, you can ask your provider.

The reports can you check from WHM access at

```
Home » Email » Mail Delivery Reports
```

and

```
Home » Email » Mail Queue Manager
```

from terminal, you can check with

```
tail -f /var/log/exim_mainlog
```

I think you've got spam from contact form on your website or some php mail script

Comment: i have root access . yes i am getting spam from contact form in my website only. how to stop such situation

Comment: put captcha to your contact form, temporarily change your outgoing ip and then whitelist your blacklisted ip

Comment: i can stop by using captcha in my contact page right. i am blocking spam mail using csf firewall, but daily spam coming from different domains. Dono how to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RBL list (Home »Service Configuration »Exim Configuration Manager » Basic Editor » RBL)
You can add more if you need it.

In ACL Options, reject emails that you think is spam, with values that you think (put higher values first, and then go down slow). Check your logs

Ratelimit suspicious SMTP servers.

Sender Verification Callouts 
Use callouts to verify the existence of email senders. Exim will connect to the mail exchanger for a given address to verify it exists before accepting mail from it.